# how to filter the array when we have inner array and need to apply filter on inner array

Tags: swift, filter, swift4

Let's say I have data as below.

```
[
    {
        hotelName : "Hotel 1",
        hotelType : 1
        prices : 
                [
                    {
                        roomType: "Single Room",
                        price : 1231
                    },
                    {
                        roomType: "Twin Room",
                        price : 1232
                    },
                    {
                        roomType: "Triple Room",
                        price : 1233
                    },
                ]
    },
    {
        hotelName : "Hotel 2",
        hotelType : 2
        prices : 
                [
                    {
                        roomType: "Single Room",
                        price : 1241
                    },
                    {
                        roomType: "Twin Room",
                        price : 1242
                    },
                    {
                        roomType: "Triple Room",
                        price : 1243
                    },
                ]
    }
]
```

What I want is to filter the hotels with price.

Let's say I want to filter to get hotel with below range.

price range as 1231-1233 >> This will return me Hotel 1 only.

price range as 1231-1431 >> This will return me Hotel 1 & Hotel 2.

I have same type of filter but there I was having 1 price only, so what I was doing is as below.

```
finalArray = finalArray.filter() {
                    CGFloat(($0.prices![0].price)!) >= minValue 
                    &&
                    CGFloat(($0.prices![0].price)!) <= maxValue
             }
```

However now I have array of prices, so I am not sure how to handle in this case.

The problem is at line

```
$0.prices![0].price
          ^^^
```

Can someone point me in right direction on how to achieve this filter?

Comment: You want to take filtered items from hotel array? I mean { roomType: String, price: Int }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to check if there are any elements in the `prices` Array that don't match the criterion. You can achieve this using `Array.contains` with the negated predicates so that `contains` returns as soon as you find a wrong value (i.e. check for values that are lower than the minimum or values that are larger than the maximum).

```
finalArray = finalArray.filter() { hotelInfo in
    !hotelInfo.prices!.contains(where: {CGFloat($0) <= minValue}) && !hotelInfo.prices!.contains(where: {CGFloat($0) >= maxValue})
}
```

Comment: What is `hotelInfo`. I understand `hotelInfo` will be 1 object of hotel... My main question is how I will be defining?

Comment: There's no need to define it, that's just the named argument of `filter`. It's the same as `$0`, but since you'll have 2 nested closures including the `where` clause of `contains`, it's more clear to name one of them.

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: `hotelInfo.prices?.contains {!(minValue..<maxValue ~= CGFloat($0))} == false`

Comment: FYI.. Negated predicates didn't work with me... so I check for positive condition and all is great...

Comment: @LeoDabus : I used `hotelInfo.prices?.contains {minValue...maxValue ~= $0}` and it works fine...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
struct Price {
   let roomType: String
   let price: Double
}

struct Hotel {
   let hotelName: String
   let hotelType: Int
   let prices: [Price]
}

let hotel1 = Hotel(hotelName: "Hotel 1", hotelType: 1, prices: [
    Price(roomType: "Single Room", price: 1231),
    Price(roomType: "Twin Room", price: 1232),
    Price(roomType: "Triple Room", price: 1233)
])

let hotel2 = Hotel(hotelName: "Hotel 2", hotelType: 1, prices: [
    Price(roomType: "Single Room", price: 1241),
    Price(roomType: "Twin Room", price: 1242),
    Price(roomType: "Triple Room", price: 1243)
])

func getHotelsInRange(_ hotels: [Hotel],
                      from min: Double,
                      to max: Double) -> [Hotel] {
    return hotels.filter { h in
        h.prices.contains{ p in
            switch p.price {
            case min...max:
                return true
            default:
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}

let result = getHotelsInRange([hotel1, hotel2], from: min, to: max)
```

Comment: **fatal error: Can't form Range with upperBound < lowerBound** for ***min...max***

Comment: Yes, looks like I’ve put arguments in wrong order. More clear would be from min to max

Comment: sure, thanks for asking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50657330/how-to-filter-current-array-using-another-array/50658598#50658598