# how to filter current array using another array

Tags: swift, filter, swift4

Let's say I have data as below.

```
[
    {
        hotelName : "Hotel 1",
        hotelType : 1
        prices : 
                [
                    {
                        roomType: "Single Room",
                        price : 1231
                    },
                    {
                        roomType: "Twin Room",
                        price : 1232
                    },
                    {
                        roomType: "Triple Room",
                        price : 1233
                    }
                ]
    },
    {
        hotelName : "Hotel 2",
        hotelType : 2
        prices : 
                [
                    {
                        roomType: "Single Room",
                        price : 1241
                    },
                    {
                        roomType: "Twin Room",
                        price : 1242
                    },
                    {
                        roomType: "Triple Room",
                        price : 1243
                    }
                ]
    }
]
```

I have another array for filter in below format.

```
[
    {
        "roomType": "Single Room"
    },
    {
        "roomType": "Twin Room"
    }
]
```

What I want to get is get room which have above types.

I am trying below way, but stuck at below point.

```
    finalArray = finalArray.filter() {
        hotelInfo in
        hotelInfo.prices!.roomType!==(
            // compare for roomType from another array
        )
    }
```

Could someone point me in right direction?

---

Struct I have is as below.

```
struct Hotels: Encodable, Decodable {
    var hotelName: String?
    var hotelType: Int?
    var prices: [RoomPrices]?
}

struct RoomPrices: Encodable, Decodable {
    var roomType: String?
    var price: Double?
}
```

For filter, I have model as below

```
struct RoomFilter: Decodable {
    var roomType: String?
}
```

---

### Prices as 1 dictionary only

```
[
    {
        hotelName : "Hotel 1",
        hotelType : 1
        prices : 
                    {
                        roomType: "Single Room",
                        price : 1231
                    }
    },
    {
        hotelName : "Hotel 2",
        hotelType : 2
        prices : 

                    {
                        roomType: "Twin Room",
                        price : 1242
                    }

    }
]
```

Updated struct will be

```
struct Hotels: Encodable, Decodable {
    var hotelName: String?
    var hotelType: Int?
    var prices: RoomPrices?
}

struct RoomPrices: Encodable, Decodable {
    var roomType: String?
    var price: Double?
}
```

Comment: So you want a `Dictionary`, whose keys are `roomTypes` and whose values are the rooms with those `roomTypes`? In any case, you should include your data struct in your question instead of showing JSONs, since it's easier to produce working code when seeing the actual types instead of their JSON representation.

Comment: @DávidPásztor : I want same array as first array but filter from second array... I have main array and I want to get hotels who fulfill second array data... So what we will check is mainArray.prices.roomType contains roomFilter.roomType I have update post with the models I have...

Comment: So you simply want to filter a `[Hotels]` to only include hotels who have all room types that are stored in `[RoomFilter]`? Do you also want to filter out the `prices` array of `Hotels` or keep all rooms there even the ones that are not present in `[RoomFilter]`? Some generic advice: you should name your types using singular form, since a single `Hotel` instance represent 1 `Hotel`, not several ones, same for `RoomPrices`. It also doesn't make sense to mark __all__ properties as optional and mutable. Declare everything as immutable and optional unless you have a good reason not to do so.

Comment: @DávidPásztor :  filter a [Hotels] to only include hotels who have **any** room types that are stored in [RoomFilter]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter an array of `Hotel`s to only keep hotels that contain a `RoomPrice` whose `roomType` property is present in an array of `RoomFilter` using two nested `contains(where:)` calls inside your `filter`, one searching `Hotel.prices` and the other one searching `roomFilters` to see if there is at least a single common element between the two arrays.

```
let filteredHotels = hotels.filter({ hotel in
    hotel.prices?.contains(where: { room in roomFilters.contains(where: {$0.roomType == room.roomType})}) ?? false
})
```

Some general advice: you should name your types using singular form, since a single `Hotel` instance represents 1 `Hotel`, not several ones, same for `RoomPrice`s. It also doesn't make sense to mark **all** properties as optional and mutable. Declare everything as immutable and optional unless you have a good reason not to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
let roomTypes = [RoomFilter(roomType: "Twin Room"), RoomFilter(roomType: "Single Room")]

let result = hotels.filter { hotel in
    hotel.prices?.contains { price in
        roomTypes.contains { rt in
            rt.roomType == price.roomType
        }
    } ?? false
}
```

Comment: just curios if prices is dictionary, what change I have to do in above logic?

Comment: could you provide an example dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

In case if a price is a dictionary:

```
let roomTypes = [RoomFilter(roomType: "Twin Room"), RoomFilter(roomType: "Single Room")]

let result = hotels.filter { hotel in
    roomTypes.contains { filterRoomType in
        filterRoomType.roomType == hotel.price?.roomType
    }
}
```